# docker run throws "invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase" using $(pwd) in volume flag

Tags: shell, docker

`docker run` throws an "invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase" error when using `$(pwd)` in the volume flag (`-v`). This is the command that is currently causing the issue:

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd)/app/polymer:/home/polymer/app jefferyb/polymer-cli polymer build
```

Comment: FYI, `$(pwd)` is extremely inefficient compared to `"$PWD"`. Any command substitution requires `fork()`ing off a subshell, setting up a FIFO to connect its output back to the main shell, reading that FIFO, `wait()`ing for the command substitution to complete, etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For my own circumstance, the output of `pwd` contained a directory with a space (i.e. /something/Problematic Directory/something-else). This was resolved by wrapping `$(pwd)` in quotation marks to explicitly identify it as a string:

```
docker run --rm -v "$(pwd)/app/polymer":/home/polymer/app jefferyb/polymer-cli polymer build
```

The documentation I read didn't use quotation marks, however this might be better practise when using variable interpolation in shell to avoid these kind of issues.